# Why does POIUtil.cfc spreadsheet code display some numbers incorrectly?

Tags: excel, coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-10, cfloop

I have a query which gets some data and displays it on on a webpage using CFLOOP and also generates a Excel file with POI:Document in ColdFusion.

```
<cfloop query="qUsedListings">
    <poi:row>
        <poi:cell type="numeric" NumberFormat="0" value="#qUsedListings.region#" />
        <poi:cell type="numeric" NumberFormat="0" value="#qUsedListings.district#" />
        <poi:cell type="numeric" NumberFormat="0" value="#qUsedListings.storeId#" />
        <poi:cell value="#qUsedListings.acquisitionAssociate#" />

        <poi:cell type="numeric" NumberFormat="0" value="#qUsedListings.listingId#" />
        <!---This above listing ID is generating duplicate values--->

        <poi:cell value="#qUsedListings.description#" />
        <poi:cell type="numeric" value="#qUsedListings.grossMarginPercentage#" />
        <poi:cell type="numeric" value="#qUsedListings.itemCost#" />
        <cfif LEN(qUsedListings.UVMAVERAGECOST)>
           <poi:cell type="numeric" value="#qUsedListings.UVMAVERAGECOST#" />
        <cfelse>
           <poi:cell  value="N/A" />
        </cfif>
```

Also when I tried to put `#qUsedListings.listingId#` in its upper cell value which is `<poi:cell value="#qUsedListings.acquisitionAssociate#" />`

I tried `<poi:cell value="#qUsedListings.acquisitionAssociate# #qUsedListings.listingId#" />`
Then the `ListingId` were coming correct in this cell with `acquisitionAssociate`, but at the same time there were duplicate and unordered values in original `ListingId` column.

Thing is that, it has different columns and all the columns are generating fine results except one viz ListingId. It is showing duplicate (or incorrect) values which is not possible. The same data which is on Webpage is correct but in Excel file it is generating duplicate/incorrect values.

For example in the image below

- The ListingID value in row 1 is `113799576`, but it should be `113799573`
- The ListingID value in row 2 is `113807824`, but it should be `113807820`

**acquisitionAssociate** [acqAsso_val   ListingId_val]

**ListingId**            [ListingId_val]

[image: EXCEL RESULTS]

[image: Check column AcquisitionAssociate and ListingID]

**UPDATE**

I tried changing the ListingId column Data type to text(string) in code then the results are coming correct. The dataType for ListingId in DATABASE is varchar, but it contains only numeric values. So the possible error here is conversion from varchar to numeric dataType in code. But I still dont know why it is happening.

Comment: Could you please provide your dump of qUsedListings query and excel result screen shot ?

Comment: I cant put the Dump right now, but u can see the correct values and wrong values in the pic I have attached.@Kannan.P

Comment: Could you please make Mark about which row and column having issue ? It's could be easy to understand for others.

Comment: Please check now @Kannan.P

Comment: try to add type attribute for acquisitionAssociate place. You have missed that attribute. By default it's consider it as Text. So that may be an problem.

Make sure, Please check query should have the correct data for the listingId columns

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the values circled in red aren't duplicates. Which listing ID values are being duplicated? *It is showing duplicate values which is not possible* Why not? Usually when you see duplicates it's either because that's what the SQL query returns OR you're using a grouped output/loop but forgot to sort the query data in the same order as the "group" columns. Try and identify if the raw query contains these "duplicates" or if they're being produced by the code?

Comment: I have checked query returns correct data and also Type attribute for acquisitionAssociate is not missed. It was intentional so bcoz I want it to be Text or String. @Kannan.P

Comment: There are 2 columns to focus on 
1. acquisitionAssociate 
2. listingId 
1 should contain acquitionAssociate ID and 2 should contain ListingId only.
For debugging purpose I also included ListingId values in the acquitionAssociate column.
So now in normal circumstances ListingId values should be same for each row in both columns but they are also coming wrong.
Also ListingIds are coming correct in acquisitionAssociate Column but wrong in ListingId's Column.
*you're using a grouped output but forgot to sort the query data in the same order as the "group" columns* Didnt get you here. @Ageax

Comment: As far as Data from query is concerned, It is actually correct otherwise Column of acquisitionAssociate wouldnt be able to show correct data. I doubt it has something to do with that ListingId column defination of something...

Comment: @VishalVerma - Ohh... now I understand.  (The usage of "duplicate" was confusing in this context. I was looking for repeating numbers...) Anyway, you're correct that the problem is due to a conversion issue.  The reason the numbers are displayed incorrectly is "ListingId" is because of the cell type and how that library handles conversions. (cont'd..)

Comment: @VishalVerma - Hope you don't mind, but I modified the title and added an example so others encountering the same issue can find this thread more easily :) Feel free to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's a conversion issue. [That library](https://github.com/bennadel/POIUtility.cfc/blob/master/lib/tags/poi/cell.cfm) handles `<poi:cell type="numeric"` by casting the input values to type [FLOAT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

```
      <cfset VARIABLES.Cell.SetCellValue( 
                        JavaCast( "float", THISTAG.GeneratedContent )
            ) />
```

Float is an approximate type [which can't represent all numbers *exactly*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). That's why some of your "Listing Id" values appear differently in the spreadsheet. For example, a number like `113807820` can't be represented precisely, and becomes `113807824` when cast as a float.

You can see it in action using this example:

```
<cfscript>
   input = "113807820";
   writeDump( JavaCast( "string", input ) );
   writeDump( numberFormat(JavaCast( "string", input), "0" ));
   writeDump( numberFormat(JavaCast( "float", input), "0") );
</cfscript>
```

Notice the resulting output is different when using float?

```
113807820  // raw string
113807820  // string + numberFormat
113807824  // float + numberFormat
```

---

**Full Demo:**

```
<cfscript>
    sheet = spreadsheetNew();

    // Correct Results: Using Adobe's type "numeric"
    sheet.setCellValue("113807820", 1, 1, "numeric");
    // Correct Results: Using type "String"
    sheet.setCellValue("113807820", 1, 2, "string");
    // Wrong Results: Cast as type "Float" 
    sheet.setCellValue(JavaCast( "float","113807820"), 1, 3);

    cfcontent (type="application/vnd.ms-excel" 
                , variable=spreadsheetReadBinary(sheet)
               );
</cfscript>
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot of Demo Spreadsheet Code]